# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in my ajaxpage

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

i am creating a new plugin,i got this error
      Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in my ajax page. how to solve this error.

this is my code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['ckballvalue'])) 
{    
$allvideos=$_REQUEST['ckballvalue'];
 $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
 global $wpdb; 
$insert_video =$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO " . $wpdb->prefix . "hdflvvideoshare (link,post_date)
VALUES ('".$allvideos."','".$now."')") or die('not inserting'); 
}

// i am calling this page by js: 
function chkbox() { 
    $('[name^=checkbox]:checked').each(function() { 
        var ckballvalue=($(this).val()); 
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "<?php echo $site_url; ?>/wp-content/plugins/<?php echo $contus; ?>/ajaxpages/ajaxpage.php", 
        data: "ckballvalue="+ckballvalue, 
        success: function(msg){ } 
    }); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Where does this code appear, how are you including it?

Comment: i am calling this page by js:    function chkbox()
{  
  
  $('[name^=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
         var ckballvalue=($(this).val());
  
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $site_url; ?>/wp-content/plugins/<?php echo $contus; ?>/ajaxpages/ajaxpage.php",
            data: "ckballvalue="+ckballvalue,   
 
            success: function(msg){
              
            }
        });
 
 
 });
 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not loading WordPress, so none of it's included framework is defined (in this particular case the `global $wpdb;` object and it's methods).

WordPress has built in way of handling ajax requests. In particular you should send the data to the url: `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')`. Included in the sent data should be the variable `action` (and which should be unique), i.e. `action:'my_action_to_do_something'`.

WordPress will then fire one of two hooks:

```
 'wp_ajax_my_action_to_do_something' //For logged in users
 'wp_ajax_noprov_my_action_to_do_something'//For non-logged in users
```

You should hook a callback function on to one or both of those hooks (depending if the action should be performed for logged in users, non-logged in users or both). The sent data can be obtained via `$_REQUEST`.

There are **loads** of [AJAX related questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax) on this site, so I would recommend reading through some of them. Also, see the [Codex pages on ajax in plug-ins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: i can not understand.please edit my code correctly.

Comment: alerdy my js code and ajaxpage code is there,you see above.please edit my code correctly and update me.

Comment: The links, particularly the Codex page, has plenty of examples to get you started, you should take a look at those.

Comment: one more thing:anyone function is not working in my ajaxpage

Comment: see error:<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function add_action() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\sankarsplugin\ajaxpages\ajaxpage.php</b> on line <b>125</b><br />

Comment: i am waiting for your answer.please help me.

Comment: just i want to insert my checkbox value in my database.

Comment: @SANS780730 please be patient, else the commenting system will notify you to stop adding a flood of comments and to continue in chat. Thanks. And please take a look at your whole code. There are plenty examples filed under [tag:ajax] on how to do it right. Your current code isn't targeting `admin-ajax.php` as Stephen Harris already stated.